how to draw this? \wire does't work


\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{quantikz}


\begin{document}
    \listofQuantikz
        \begin{quantikz}
        \lstick{$\ket{a}$} & \ctrl{1} & \ctrl{2} & \ctrl{3} & \ctrl{4} & \qw \\
        \lstick{$\ket{y_0}$} &\ctrl{-1} \wire [1] [1] ["\frac{\pi}{16}"{above, pos=0.2}]{a}&&&&\\
        \lstick{$\ket{y_1}$} &&\ctrl{-2} \wire [1] [1] ["\frac{\pi}{8}"{above, pos=0.2}]{a}&&&\\
        \lstick{$\ket{y_2}$} &&&\ctrl{-3} \wire [1] [1] ["\frac{\pi}{4}"{above, pos=0.2}]{a}&&\\
        \lstick{$\ket{y_3}$} &&&&\ctrl{-4} \wire [1] [1] ["\frac{\pi}{2}"{above, pos=0.2}]{a}&\\
    \end{quantikz}
\end{document}


Welcome. // Usually …‘ll get better ….lts when we don’t h..e to guess what .ou did. I.e. please post only code, which compiles. Thank you

I've updated the code to report an error, but you can see the runout

Thank you, that's better. However, probably most packages laoded aren't needed. \listofQuantix doesn't seem to exist; same probably for \lstick. Using this package is described differently ... in a nutshell: I can't compile it. // Please understand every helping member here is a volunteer. Bye

No circuitikz involved, I'll remove the tag.

@GuanyuLi: Can you provide a better title for your question. Something other than "how to draw this?"

The first argument in that example from the documentation is not a 1 but an l, in general this is the direction l/r/u/d being left/right/up/down as documented slightly later in the documentation under \wire[d][n][s]{t}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{quantikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{quantikz}
    \lstick{$\ket{a}$} & \ctrl{1} & \ctrl{2} & \ctrl{3} & \ctrl{4} & \qw \\
    \lstick{$\ket{y_0}$} &\ctrl{-1} \wire[l][1]["p"{above, pos=0.2}]{a}&&&&\\
    \lstick{$\ket{y_1}$} &&\ctrl{-2} \wire[l][1]["p"{above, pos=0.2}]{a}&&&\\
    \lstick{$\ket{y_2}$} &&&\ctrl{-3} \wire[l][1]["p"{above, pos=0.2}]{a}&&\\
    \lstick{$\ket{y_3}$} &&&&\ctrl{-4} \wire[l][1]["p"{above, pos=0.2}]{a}&\\
  \end{quantikz}
\end{document}

